# "single-row subquery returns more than one row"

Tags: mysql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Good evening!
I have a problem that I can't figure out how to solve. The query I want to run should change every person's email address to a given one, but I get the error message "single-row subquery returns more than one row"

```
update employees
set email =  ( select regexp_replace(email,'@([a-z])+','@company')
              from employees
             )
where id = (select id
        from employees);
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: which RDBMS are you using here, mysql or oracle? 2 different animals here.

Comment: What @JNevill said; but you can probably just get rid of the entire `WHERE` clause completely; or, if settings forbid a where-less `UPDATE`, replace it with `WHERE 1=1`

Answer (score 0):

```
update employees 
set email = regexp_replace(email,'@([a-z])+','@company') 
where id IN (select id from employees);
```

Your first subquery is pointless and doesn't work, your second one in the WHERE clause needs to be changed to an IN operator.

Furthermore, the WHERE statement makes no sense. You are already updating every id in the Employee table. So just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

if your second subquery returns only one row then you can use

`update employees 
 set email =  ( select regexp_replace(email,'@([a-z])+','@company')
              where id = (select id from employees);`

else if your second subquery return more than one row then you should use

`update employees
set email =  ( select regexp_replace(email,'@([a-z])+','@company')
          where id IN (select id from employees);`

> Blockquote

Because IN will check for a value whichever given by the subquery result.
But '=' require only one equivalent value from the subquery result.